# how to pass string value from one class to another

Tags: iphone

I just want to know that how to pass the string value from one class to another..

Actually i have two classes.In first class i fetch string value from the array and i just want to use this string value into my second class.Now i don't know how to pass value between this two classes.Please give me some idea to do that.Should i use some class method to pass the value.But i don't know how to use this class methods.How i create the class methods to set the values from one class and then get the same value from class methods.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Class1.h:

```
@interface Class1 : NSObject
{
    NSArray *arr;
}

- (NSString *)myString;

@end
```

Class1.m:

```
@implementation Class1

- (NSString *)myString
{
    return [arr objectAtIndex:0];
}

@end
```

Class2.h:

```
@interface Class2 : NSObject
{
}

- (void)methodThatUsesStringFromClass1:(Class1 *)c1;

@end
```

Class2.m:

```
@implementation Class2

- (void)methodThatUsesStringFromClass1:(Class1 *)c1
{
    NSLog(@"The string from class 1 is %@", [c1 myString]);
}

@end
```

Comment: @RavuAlHemio....should i use class method like this  +(NSMutableString*)getString;
+(void)setString:(NSMutableString*)str;

Comment: Why a class method? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sir...i am made a common variable class where i define a class method..From my another class i have a array.From my array i pick myarr[16] value and send it to the class method.And from there i can access the string value.....I think i m doing right...tell me sir i m right or doing some wrong...?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to define public `@property` in class where you want to pass your object, for example, for NSString:

```
// CustomClassA.h
@interface CustomClassA : NSObject
{
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *publicString;
@end

// CustomClassA.m
@implementation CustomClassA
@synthesize publicString;
@end
```

In your sender:

```
//somewhere defined CustomClassA objectA;
[objectA setPublicString:@"newValue"];
```

But you should understand what means `retain`, `@synthesize` and other. Also it is not your current question.

Comment: @Nekto....should i use class method like this  +(NSMutableString*)getString;
+(void)setString:(NSMutableString*)str;

Comment: @synthesize will automatically create such methods for your `string`

Answer (score 0):

you can use appDelegate.YourStringVaraible =@"store your string";

and then use this YourStringVaraible  in any class by using appDelegate.YourStringVaraible

Answer (score 0):

pass the string parameter by overriding the `init` method.

Class1.m

```
@implementation Class1

Class2 *class2 = [[Class2 alloc] initWithString:myString];
...


@end
```

Class2.h

```
@interface Class2 : NSObject
{
NSString *string2;
}
@end
```

Class2.m

```
-(id) initWithString:(NSString*)str  {
    self = [super init];     
    if(self) {    
        string2 = str;
    }     
    return(self); 
}
```